# Handling Key Pressed Events + WinForms + Validation + Cancel

Tags: winforms, validation, events, keypress

I am implementing a WinForms form in a C# project.
My form is a child of a MDI form.
My form contains a user control.
My user control contains some buttons including a validation button and a cancel one.

I want to implement the following logic :

- When my form is active and the user presses the enter key then I want the validation button clicked event to be fired automatically.
- When my form is active and the user presses the escape key then I want the cancel button clicked event to be fired automatically.

If my validation and my cancel buttons were not included in a user control then I would probably set the AcceptButton and CancelButton properties of my form.

Comment: in the OnLoad of the control you can get the parent form using FindForm() and then set it's AcceptButton and CancelButton properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code I have written in the Load event handler of my user control according to a tip given by Arthur in a comment to my first post :

```
// Get the container form.
form = this.FindForm();

// Simulate a click on the validation button
// when the ENTER key is pressed from the container form.
form.AcceptButton = this.cmdValider;

// Simulate a click on the cancel button
// when the ESC key is pressed from the container form.
form.CancelButton = this.cmdAnnulerEffacer;
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Set the KeyPreview Property of your from true from properties;
2. Add keyDownEvent to your Form
3. In keyDownEvent of your Form, include following lines of code

The code

```
 if(e.KeyValue==13)// When Enter Key is Pressed
 {
     // Last line is performing click. Other lines are making sure
     // that user is not writing in a Text box
      Control ct = userControl1 as Control;
      ContainerControl cc = ct as ContainerControl;
      if (!(cc.ActiveControl is TextBox))
          validationButton.PerformClick(); // Code line to performClick
 }

 if(e.KeyValue==27) // When Escape Key is Pressed
 {
     // Last line is performing click. Other lines are making sure
     // that user is not writing in a Text box
      Control ct = userControl1 as Control;
      ContainerControl cc = ct as ContainerControl;
      if (!(cc.ActiveControl is TextBox))
          cancelButton.PerformClick(); // Code line to performClick
 }
```

validationButton or cancelButton are the names of your buttons which I am just supposing. You may have different ones. Use Your names instead of these two if you have different.

Comment: If any problem to implement any of the instructions you should update.

Comment: I have followed the tip given by Arthur in a comment to my post. I have not followed your tip because of one reason. If the user is typing in a TextBox and then he presses the enter key then I have to perform a test for not calling validationButton.PerformClick.

Comment: Ok. Sorry for that I could not get the case you mentioned from the problem statement. Is your problem solved?

Comment: Yes. I have added some code into the OnLoad event handler of my user control as mentionned by Arthur. But thanks for your help.

Comment: That is OK. You Should Share that, accept that and I will vote-up. And that will be helpful for the new comers.